# Difference between .queue() and jquery.queue()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, queue

Might be a silly question, but I am confused between `.queue()` used with `.dequeue()` and `$.queue()` OR `jquery.queue()`.

Are they the same, if so why jquery provided them in 2 separate documentations? Can, someone explain their ussage differences along with appropriate examples ?

https://api.jquery.com/queue/

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.queue/

Comment: the first one is applied to a jquery object, it means for all "selected" elements, while the second one to one element only

Comment: That helped. Thnx pavel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.queue()` is used as a method of the jQuery element.

It has only one parameter "queueName"

```
$("div:first").queue("fx")
```

Whereas `jquery.queue()` is a standalone function that will accept DOM element as it's first parameter and second for name of the queue.

```
jQuery.queue($("div:first")[0], "fx" );
```

Both works same, just the approach is different.

Comment: This means, we dont need to use '$.queue()' or '$.dequeue()' separately, as we can do all that work with help of ".queue()" and ".dequeue()" eazily ?

Comment: Yes, we don't need to do.
jQuery team has documented both Lower level and Higher level methods.

Comment: Is there any other function for which jQuery Team has documented both "Lower" & "Higher" Level methods apart from .queue() & .dequeue() ?

Comment: Yes, another example is .data() (https://api.jquery.com/data/) and jQuery.data() (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)

Answer (score 1):

As said at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.queue/

> Note: This is a low-level method, you should probably use .queue() instead.

Internally `$(selector).queue()` and `$(selector).dequeue()` use `$.queue()` and `$.dequeue()` respectively.

This is the code for `$(selector).queue()` and `$(selector).dequeue()` jQuery 2.1.3:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    queue: function( type, data ) {
        var setter = 2;

        if ( typeof type !== "string" ) {
            data = type;
            type = "fx";
            setter--;
        }

        if ( arguments.length < setter ) {
            return jQuery.queue( this[0], type );
        }

        return data === undefined ?
            this :
            this.each(function() {
                var queue = jQuery.queue( this, type, data ); // <-- HERE!

                // Ensure a hooks for this queue
                jQuery._queueHooks( this, type );

                if ( type === "fx" && queue[0] !== "inprogress" ) {
                    jQuery.dequeue( this, type ); // <-- HERE!
                }
            });
    },
    dequeue: function( type ) {
        return this.each(function() {
            jQuery.dequeue( this, type ); // <-- HERE!
        });
    },

....
```